# How to parse a JSON array in Python

Tags: python, json

My JSON array is as follows and I would like to build a new string that would output accordingly.

I have a simple function just to see if I can return a value but it's failing with `Error was expected string or buffer`

```
def blah(myjson):
    data = json.loads(myjson)
    for item in data:
        result = item['svn_tag']

    return result
```

JSON:

```
[{'svn_tag': '20150623r3', 'module': 'api'}, {'svn_tag': '20150624r1', 'module': 'ui'}]
```

Proposed Output:

```
api - 20150623r3, ui - 20150623r3
```

Comment: Single quotes are not valid JSON.  You have to use double-quotes.

Comment: Fixed thx for catching that. It was correct in my codebase.

Comment: well the interesting thing is that Ansible is returning it w/ single quotes. My JSON in the source file has double quotes but when I return the variable it converts everything to single quotes.

Comment: I take it back it is double quotes, the output is just in single quote.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `json` wants the strings and field names encoded in double quotes and not single quotes. So either replace manually the single quotes or use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) since the string is also a python valid literal:

```
import ast

def blah(myjson):
    data = ast.literal_eval(myjson)
    return ', '.join(item['module'] + ' - ' + item['svn_tag'] for item in data)

s = '''[{'svn_tag': '20150623r3', 'module': 'api'}, {'svn_tag': '20150624r1', 'module': 'ui'}]'''
print blah(s)
```

Result:

```
api - 20150623r3, ui - 20150624r1
```

Comment: grrrr so it's telling me there's a Keyerror for module and svn_tag. `return ', '.join(item['svn_tag'] for item in data) KeyError: 'svn_tag`

Comment: Do you use the same string? Otherwise check if svn_tag is defined for each array entry.

Comment: i think it's an Ansible thing so ignore the Keyerror. So I'm pretty sure the string/variable that I'm passing in is this `[{'svn_tag': '20150624r1_6.36_gameofthrones', 'module': 'ariaapi'}]` because if I return the variable that i passed to the function that's what gets displayed. However, running it through the function you have, it's throwing a `ValueError: malformed string`

Comment: This is because the variable isn't a string but an already python array. So skip the whole parsing thing and use `', '.join(item['module'] + ' - ' + item['svn_tag'] for item in variable_name)`

Comment: Ughhh ... so w/o the `data = ast.literal_eval(myjson)` line and with only `return ', '.join(item['module'] + ' - ' + item['svn_tag'] for item in myjson)` yields `KeyError: 'module'`

Comment: I notice you wrap the sample JSON array within three single quotes. Is that something I need to consider?

Comment: `print type(myjson)` and `print(myjson)` and tell me the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84624/discussion-between-juniorcompressor-and-luckytaxi).